# Disabling Spybot S&D TeaTimer

Tags: spybot-sd

Does anyone know how to permanently disable the Spybot S&D TeaTimer without uninstalling and reinstalling Spybot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go in to Spybot's advanced settings (Mode > Advanced), then expand Tools and click Resident, and untick the option "Resident "TeaTimer" (Protection of over-all system settings) active."

[image]

If this fails, the quickest way is to go in to the registry / regedit and go to the following key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Then delete the TeaTimer entry.

Answer (score 1):

rather than **deleting** registry entries, i recommend to use **[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)** (Sysinternals' excellent startup management utility) to **disable** the program instead.

*Autoruns is freeware and portable, no installation required.*